# Elements refusing to resize?

Tags: html, css

Looked up the heirarchy to see if there was a problem with no defined initial element because I'm mostly using percentages, but that isn't it. I even set a max-height of 5px to my container div to see if that was the issue, but nothing reacted. I've been pulling my hair out over this one. I'm trying to line up the UL height exactly with the video height and have overflow scrollbars to contain the rest of the tabs.

HTML:

```
<div class="video-portfolio">
        <div class="video-nav-contain">
            <ul class="video-nav">
                <li id="hide1">
                    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'garageBar')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/garage-bar-tab.png" onClick="videoDisplay1">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="hide2">
                    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'murryLake')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/murry-lake-tab.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="hide3">
                    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'roofFun')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/roof-fun-tab.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="hide4">
                    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'westsideClean')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/westsideClean-tab.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="garageBar" class="tabcontent" id="videoName">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/garage%20bar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="murryLake" class="tabcontent" style=" display: none;">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/murry%20lake2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="roofFun" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/rooftop%20fun.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="westsideClean" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/westside%20cleanup.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.video-portfolio {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
max-height: 500px;
}

.vid-tabs {
width:80%;
}

.video-nav {
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
padding: 0;

}

.video-nav-contain {
width: 20%;
overflow: scroll;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
max-height: 10%;
}

.tab-icon {
padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: `<ul>` has default margins. Add `.video-nav { margin: 0 }`.

Comment: That cleaned it up a little bit, but did nothing to help with my current task at hand, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. So... you're trying to make the nav, whose max-height you set to `10%`, the same height as the video?

Comment: threw that max-height: 10% in there to see if I could get something to resize.

Comment: That didn't work, the video-portfolio-contain height:500px didn't work. I am so competently dumbfounded right now.

Comment: Seems like `float` is messing with you. If you set `.video-portfolio{ height: 500px }` it works, but not with `max-height`... I think the easiest approach here would be a flexbox, but [browser support is still not state of the art](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) there...

Comment: With that bad of support, it's really not something I can use. Using height instead of max-height isn't changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If using **flexbox** isn't an option then maybe **table** is?

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/mypxxbbw/

I only wrapped your *.tabcontent* inside a *.tabcontent-wrapper* and applied `display: table-cell` to this and *.video-nav-contain*.

Then I added the following **CSS** undearneath yours (so you can see, what I actually added or would have removed easier):

```
video-portfolio {
  display: table;
}
.tacontent-wrapper, .video-nav-contain {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none; /* no float needed */
}
.video-nav-contain {
  overflow: hidden; /* move overflow from here to ul */
}
.video-nav-contain > ul.video-nav {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll; /* the overflow from above */
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```